# Basic4android how to explode a string and convert to array

Tags: basic4android

I am trying to separate the characters of string.

```
 Dim res As String
            res = "1+2+3+4+")
            tempArr = Regex.split("\+", res)
```

I am using this code to convert the string into array.Is it correct ? and also i need to know the count of the array. How it possible to get the count of the array ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct.

```
Dim res As String = "1+2+3+4+"
Dim numbers() As String = Regex.Split("\+", res)
Log(numbers.Length)
For Each n As String In Numbers
  Log(n)
Next
```